# Failed to map the path '/' with asp.net development server

Tags: asp.net

I have used following code to change web.config at run time

```
Configuration conf = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~/");
conf.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings["ApplicationServices"].ConnectionString = "Test";
    conf.Save();
```

But I am getting an error - "Failed to map the path '/'." I have searched on internet and worked on all the solutions like 
1. Change the path to "/"
2. Change the path to "~/"

but same issue occurred. There is one point I would like to say is my application is not hosted on IIS, but running though visuals studio using asp.net development server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `~` with `HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath`

i.e.

`Configuration conf = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration(HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath)`

`~` should work, I suggested `ApplicationPath` to be sure of Virtual Directory differences when hosted on IIS instead of VS DevServer.

In fact if you are targetting `web.config` in root, then you just need to pass `null` as the parameter. No need for passing `~`.

Edit:

Are you working with administrative privilege? For this to work on VS Development Server, you have to start Visual Studio with adminstrator privileges. Right-click Visual Studio and `Run As Administrator`.

Comment: Hi Still I am facing the same issue

Comment: Hi There is one more addition I have done in web.config <asp enableParentPaths="true"></asp> inside <system.webServer> because I have read in a thread that this setting should be enabled in IIS. So for making this settings enabled for a single application I have done this change in web.config

Comment: Start Visual Studio with `Run As Adminstrator`. Updated my answer.

Comment: It works thanks a lot. But I don't know how to make this comment as an answer

Comment: Indeed, `HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath` works both during development and when deployed to the IIS.

Comment: My situation was that "/web.config" as a parameter worked during development but it failed without reporting an error when deployed on IIS (`appSetings` properties couldn't be read).